# Two Django projects with same database - permission denied for relation django_migrations

Tags: django, psql, django-migrations

I have two django projects that are not connected in any way, both on localhost. I want to have them both use the same database.

I am trying to create migrations on the second project after the first one succeeded but, I am getting an exception:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation django_migrations
```

My setup is as follows:

```
//First project
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'srt_side_by_side',
        'USER': 'srt_side_by_side_admin',
        'PASSWORD': '******************',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
//Second project
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'srt_side_by_side',
        'USER': 'srt_side_by_side_admin_2',
        'PASSWORD': '**************',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I have granted SUPERUSER privileges to both users.
I have tried to set individual privileges while being connected as the corresponding user in the psql shell.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to srt_side_by_side_admin_2;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to srt_side_by_side_admin_2;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public to srt_side_by_side_admin_2;
```

The DB access privileges in the psql shell:

```
=Tc/simeonparvanov
simeonparvanov=CTc/simeonparvanov   
srt_side_by_side_admin=CTc/simeonparvanov 
srt_side_by_side_admin_2=CTc/simeonparvanov
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is the format i use GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that both project have their own migration files and they conflict, the solution is choosing only one project to manage your databases (migration and changes) and the other project should only connect to database (without changing db structure)

assuming you've already choose your main project (the one that runs migrations) I can think of two solutions for your second project

- run migrations for secons project with `--fake` argument: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate)

> Tells Django to mark the migrations as having been applied or unapplied, but without actually running the SQL to change your database schema.

- in your model class for second project set meta options `managed` to `False` (it tells django that you will manually handle db creation and migration for this model [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed)

sample code:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # fields
    # ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

Comment: The migrations passed. But now when I try to run the project and try to access it in the browser I get an exceptions that the db tables are not set.

Comment: maybe the error stack trace helps finding the issue

Comment: This is in my opinion the best solution. It is a clean approach and guards against future problems.

Comment: I destroyed the virtualenv, deleted all files and started over clean. Finally it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create two separate users. for more info checkout https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/uA_XyGYKn2o/km80RXBB2uMJ

Comment: Then I am getting django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist I have tried to ./manage.py makemigrations auth, etc.. doesn't work

Comment: After makemigration did you run migrate?

Comment: I did but it was a mess from all the chaotic testing.

Answer (score 1):

Are your projects does not have any relation and you just want to run only one instance of postgres server? 
If so, than you just need to create two separate databases in postgres, set your user to own both of them, and then set their names in field `name` of config.

Something like:

`CREATE DATABASE srt_side_by_side_2 OWNER srt_side_by_side_admin;`

And then for the second project config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'srt_side_by_side_2',
        'USER': 'srt_side_by_side_admin',
        'PASSWORD': '**************',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```